# Why I get different plan sketch for my program?

Tags: apache-flink

I am running a program in a cluster over the same dataset with exactly the same configuration several times. Interestingly, I get slightly different sketch for my program in the web interface. Mainly the connections between the tasks vary from time to time. Can anyone say what could be the reason?
Here is the plans for two runs.
[image: First Run]
[image: Second Run]

Comment: I assume that some of the edges are simply not properly drawn. Are you using locally and on your cluster the same version? Judging from the operators, the plan looks identically.

Comment: Operators are identical in all runs but edges are different. It is on a remote cluster and version flink-0.10.0.

Comment: I guess it's only a rendering issue and shouldn't affect the correctness of your job's result.

Comment: I confirm that the layout algorithm for drawing the plan is not deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Fabian!